# How do I put text and shadow over my thumbnails (php)?

Tags: wordpress, list, thumbnails, css

I have a results list of thumbnails with text underneath. I would like to put the text as white with a shadow rectangle over the base of the thumbnails instead. Anyone know how to achieve this in the following code?

Thanks in advance :)

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<div id="page-<?php echo $paged ?>">


    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true) )
            $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'location', true);
        else
            $make_address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_street', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_city', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_state', true) . '&nbsp;' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cp_zipcode', true);
        ?>

        <div id="post-id-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post-wrapper">

            <div class="post-block">
                <?php if ( is_sticky() ) echo '<strong>FEATURED</strong>'; ?>

             <div class="grid_100">
             <?php if ( get_option('cp_ad_images') == 'yes' ) cp_ad_loop_thumbnail(); ?>

                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( mb_strlen( get_the_title() ) >= 75 ) echo mb_substr( get_the_title(), 0, 75 ).'...'; else the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="post-desc">
        <?php echo $make_address; ?>
                    <div class="post-debug">

                        <!--<h4>Description:</h4>
                        <?php echo cp_get_content_preview( 160 ); ?>--!>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /post-block -->
        </div><!-- /post-wrapper -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- /page --> 

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="block"><center>Sorry, no results found...</center></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Wordpress issue, you need to use CSS to solve this. Try [box-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) to create shadows over the thumbnails.

Comment: The shadows are a secondary concern. How do I make the text                 <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( mb_strlen( get_the_title() ) >= 75 ) echo mb_substr( get_the_title(), 0, 75 ).'...'; else the_title(); ?></a></h3> sit over the thumbnails layer              <?php if ( get_option('cp_ad_images') == 'yes' ) cp_ad_loop_thumbnail(); ?>

Comment: Also with CSS, wrap your image into a div with position relative and width/height defined, then put you <h3> inside this div with position absolute. Probably you'll need to adjust some z-index to make it work.

Comment: This is the CSS for post-block : #list .post-block {
 font: 12px/1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding: 4px 6px;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #efefef;
 overflow: hidden;
}
Can you please explain how to implement the layers?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you need. Is that what you are tying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/YrLYE/

Comment: http://musicnetwork.co - I'm trying to make the text appear over the base of the thumbnails. The code for the results list is above.

Comment: The previous jsfiddle I sent would help. Anyway, here's another suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/X9QSg/1/

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I've spent six hours trying to implement these scripts into the php code to no avail. Just lots of piled up text in the wrong places. If you're making assumptions about my knowledge, this could be the problem. I just trial and error over and over and over and over again. None of my attempts have been successful.